# catkin package cannot find own message type (python)

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a package called [skeleton_markers](https://github.com/pirobot/skeleton_markers/tree/hydro-devel) that I am in the process of converting from rosbuild to catkin.  The package builds fine and I remembered to do a 'source devel/setup.bash' after compiling.  But when I try to run a Python node (in the same package) that imports a message type defined in my package, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/patrick/catkin_ws/src/skeleton_markers/nodes/skeleton_markers.py", line 24, in <module>
    from skeleton_markers.msg import Skeleton
  File "/home/patrick/Dropbox/Robotics/catkin_ws/src/skeleton_markers/nodes/skeleton_markers.py", line 24, in <module>
    from skeleton_markers.msg import Skeleton
ImportError: No module named msg
```

When I run rosmsg on the message type, I get back the correct response:

```
$ rosmsg show skeleton_markers/Skeleton std_msgs/Header header
  uint32 seq
  time stamp
  string frame_id
int32 user_id
string[] name
float32[] confidence
geometry_msgs/Vector3[] position
  float64 x
  float64 y
  float64 z
geometry_msgs/Quaternion[] orientation
  float64 x
  float64 y
  float64 z
  float64 w
```

So I'm guessing I'm missing a key ingredient that allows a Python node to import my message type.  Here are my package.xml and CMakeLists.txt files.  The Python node I am trying to run is [skeleton_markers.py](https://github.com/pirobot/skeleton_markers/blob/hydro-devel/nodes/skeleton_markers.py).

My package.xml file:

```
<package>
  <name>skeleton_markers</name>
  <version>0.4.0</version>
  <description>
   Skeleton Markers: Publish a list of joint markers 
   for viewing in RViz.
  </description>

  <maintainer email="patrick@pirobot.org">Patrick Goebel</maintainer>
  <license>BSD</license>
  <url type="website">http://ros.org/wiki/skeleton_markers</url>
  <url type="https://github.com/pirobot/skeleton_markers/issues"></url>
  <author email="patrick@pirobot.org">Patrick Goebel</author>

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>

  <build_depend>libopenni-dev</build_depend>
  <build_depend>libopenni-nite-dev</build_depend>
  <build_depend>libopenni-sensor-primesense-dev</build_depend>
  <build_depend>geometry_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>tf</build_depend>
  <build_depend>orocos_kdl</build_depend>
  <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
  <build_depend>visualization_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>geometry_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>openni_camera</build_depend>
  <build_depend>openni_tracker</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>

  <run_depend>libopenni-dev</run_depend>
  <run_depend>libopenni-nite-dev</run_depend>
  <run_depend>libopenni-sensor-primesense-dev</run_depend>
  <run_depend>geometry_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>orocos_kdl</run_depend>
  <run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>
  <run_depend>visualization_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>geometry_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>tf</run_depend>
  <run_depend>openni_camera</run_depend>
  <run_depend>openni_tracker</run_depend>
  <run_depend>rospy</run_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>

</package>
```

My CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(skeleton_markers)

find_package(orocos_kdl REQUIRED)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  tf
  geometry_msgs
  message_generation)

# Find OpenNI
find_package(PkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(OpenNI REQUIRED libopenni)

# Find Nite
find_path(Nite_INCLUDEDIR
          NAMES XnVNite.h
          HINTS /usr/include/nite /usr/local/include/nite)
find_library(Nite_LIBRARY
             NAMES XnVNite_1_3_1
             HINTS /usr/lib /usr/local/lib
             PATH_SUFFIXES lib) 

link_directories(
  ${catkin_LIBRARY_DIRS}
  ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}
  ${orocos_kdl_LIBRARY_DIRS}
  ${OpenNI_LIBRARIES}
  ${Nite_LIBRARY}
)

include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDEDIR}
                    ${OpenNI_INCLUDEDIR}
                    ${Nite_INCLUDEDIR}
                    ${orocos_kdl_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

add_message_files (
  FILES
  Skeleton.msg
)

generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES geometry_msgs std_msgs
)

catkin_package(
    DEPENDS rospy roscpp visualization_msgs std_msgs geometry_msgs
    openni_camera openni_tracker tf
    CATKIN-DEPENDS message_runtime
    INCLUDE_DIRS # TODO
    LIBRARIES # TODO
)

add_executable(skeleton_tracker
  src/skeleton_tracker.cpp
  src/KinectController.cpp
  src/KinectDisplay.cpp)

target_link_libraries(skeleton_tracker
  glut
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
  ${OpenNI_LIBRARIES}
  ${Nite_LIBRARY}
  ${orocos_kdl_LIBRARIES})

install(TARGETS skeleton_tracker RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION})
```

Thanks!
patrick

**UPDATE**: I added the following setup.py file to the top level of my skeleton_markers package and I added the line:

```
catkin_python_setup()
```

to my CMakeLists.txt file.  Unfortunately, this did not fix the import problem even after a clean rebuild and doing a 'source devel/setup.bash'.

setup.py:

```
## ! DO NOT MANUALLY INVOKE THIS setup.py, USE CATKIN INSTEAD

from distutils.core import setup
from catkin_pkg.python_setup import generate_distutils_setup

# fetch values from package.xml
setup_args = generate_distutils_setup(
    packages=['skeleton_markers'],
    package_dir={'': 'src'})

setup(**setup_args)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/113671/catkin-package-cannot-find-own-message-type-(python)/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2013-12-29

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-12-29**:
Was it built successfully? Your Python message file should be in your workspace at: devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/skeleton_markers/msg/_Skeleton.py

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2013-12-29**:
Yes, the package builds successfully and the msg file you refer to does exist in the correct location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think your problem is that your python script is called skeleton_markers.py, and python is looking for the msg module in that script. If you rename it such that it doesn't have the same name as your package, does it work?

---

Originally posted by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) with karma: 1780 on 2013-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 15

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2013-12-29**:
Awesome!  That was it exactly.  Never would have thought of that...Many thanks!

**Comment by [jpaulos](https://answers.ros.org/users/12591/jpaulos/) on 2014-02-28**:
Had a similar issue, also solved my problem.  Note that you will need clear out the old .pyc file as well, if it exists.

**Comment by [antonio](https://answers.ros.org/users/23427/antonio/) on 2016-06-22**:
This solved my problem *_*

**Comment by [Falko](https://answers.ros.org/users/23523/falko/) on 2016-12-15**:
In my case there was another - currently unused - file with the same name within that directory. Never thought of it until reading this post.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should not modify the output directories for libraries and executables - remove the following lines from your CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
```

When invoking `catkin_package()` the optional keyword argument is `CATKIN_DEPENDS` (not `CATKIN-DEPENDS`). Please consider reading http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/howto/index.html for more information when to use `DEPENDS` and when to use `CATKIN_DEPENDS`.

You should also consider filling in the other optional arguments of `catkin_package()`. While it will not affect your package directly it does affect packages which would depend on your package.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-12-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-12-29**:
You should update your version of `catkinize` if it generated the `CATKIN-DEPENDS` for you. This typo has been fixed 9 months ago.

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2013-12-29**:
Thanks for the clarification.  Unfortunately, removing those two lines and recompiling did not solve the import problem.  Also, you are correct that I was using an older version of the catkinize script because the newest version crashes as reported here:  https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/catkinize/issues/38#issuecomment-31316935

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-12-29**:
My above comments will not address your import problem but only point out additional problems in the posted code. Please follow the previously given advice to create a "setup.py" file and use "catkin_python_setup()" for that.

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2013-12-29**:
OK, I added a setup.py file as explained in the link in @joq's Update and I added the catkin_python_setup() line to my CMakeLists.txt file.  Then I did a 'rm -rf devel build', 'catkin_make' and 'source devel/setup.bash' but the import error remains.

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2013-12-29**:
@Dirk Thomas - just an FYI that I updated my question with my setup.py file.  Not sure if I have to add something to that file specific to message files.